# Node leveldown under Ubuntu: undefined symbol error on require

Tags: node.js, leveldb

I have node v0.11.9 installed with nvm under Ubuntu 12.04 precise and leveldown@0.10.2 (compiled without warnings), but when I try to load leveldown I get the following error:

```
$ node
> require ('leveldown')
Error: /home/direvius/learn/leveldb/node_modules/leveldown/build/Release/leveldown.node: undefined symbol: _ZN4node12MakeCallbackEN2v86HandleINS0_6ObjectEEENS1_INS0_8FunctionEEEiPNS1_INS0_5ValueEEE
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at bindings (/home/direvius/learn/leveldb/node_modules/leveldown/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/direvius/learn/leveldb/node_modules/leveldown/index.js:1:99)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: use node v0.10.x

I've opened an issue on github: https://github.com/rvagg/node-leveldown/issues/83